# Kendo grid in edit mode doesn't fire push event

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

My grid is build like this:

```
 @(Html.Kendo().Grid<MyProject.Models.DataObjects.MyObject>()
        .Name("my-object-grid")
        .Columns(columns =>
        {
            columns.Bound(p => p.ID).Hidden();
            columns.Bound(p => p.Name).Width(300);
            columns.Command(command =>
            {
                command.Edit().Text("Modify")
                    .UpdateText("Save")
                    .CancelText("Cancel")
                    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:90px;height:30px;font-size:12px;" });
                command.Destroy().Text("Delete").HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:90px;height:30px;font-size:12px;" });
            }).Width(220);
        })
        .ToolBar(toolbar => toolbar.Create().Text("Add").HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:120px;height:30px;float:left;" }))
        .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.PopUp)
        .Window(win => win.Title("MyObject")).TemplateName("MyObject"))
        .Pageable()
        .Sortable()
        .Scrollable()
        .Filterable()
        .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height:430px;" })
        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
            .Ajax()
            .PageSize(10)
            .Model(model => 
            { 
                model.Id(p => p.ID);
            })
            .Create(update => update.Action("MyObject_Create", "MyObject"))
            .Read(read => read.Action("MyObject_Read", "MyObject"))
            .Update(update => update.Action("MyObject_Update", "MyObject"))
            .Destroy(update => update.Action("MyObject_Delete", "MyObject"))
                    .Events(evt => evt.Push("myObjectGridDataSource_push").Error("myObjectGridDataSource_error"))
         )
)
```

And the foolwingo javacript handlers are defined after:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function myObjectGridDataSource_push(e) {
    alert(e.type);
}

function myObjectGridDataSource_error(e) {
    alert(e.status);
}
</script>
```

The javascript generated by the helper seems to be ok, but the event handlers are never fired when I add/edit/remove some item of the grid. But the requests to the controller are working fine.

Could be this related to the edit mode of the grid (using popup)?
I can't find what I am doing wrong...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Push is invoked during dataSource transport initialization which sets up push notifications. The data source will call this function only once and provide callbacks which will handle push notifications (data pushed from the server).

[Push event Detailed information](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/framework/datasource#configuration-transport.push)

If you can tell what exactly you are trying to achieve then I can be of a bit more help. Also if you want to catch the event before the record id being udpated or inserted or deleted then push won't do it. You will need to implement the **sync** event of the grid.

Comment: Ok, I misunderstood what the push event is for. What I need is: when I create a new object, and it is successfully created, the id of the newly object is returned by the `MyObject_Create()` method and I want to get this id and redirect the user to some other page based on this id. There is an event where I can get the response? Can you help me with this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You will need to implement dataBinding event on your grid and capture the new created object from there.

Comment: But databinding is fired when I do sorting, paging... How can I detect the new created object if I don't have the id?

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention that you will need to wright a condition to verify if the action is a sync action or other, Also you might need to maintain a flag to verify if the Object is new in condition to avoid redirection in updation. Add the below condition    
  **if (e.action == "sync") {   }**

Comment: I solved the problem. I used the `RequestEnd` event of the datasource, checked if `event.type == "create"` and get the new object created like `var newObject = event.response[0];`! As you have clarified me about the push event I will accept your answer ;)